# How to show that the limit function fullfills $|F(z)| = 1$ for $|z|=1$ using the maximum principle?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, maximum-principle, analytic-continuation

Let $D\subset \mathbb{C}$ be bounded by $|z| = 1$ and some continuum $C$ in $|z| < 1$ such that $0 \not \in D$. The sequence $(f_n)$ of holomorphic and injective functions is defined on $D$ and every domain $f_n(D)$ is bounded by $|z| = 1$ and some continuum $C_n$ in $|z| < 1$ such that $0 \not \in f_n(D)$ (just like $D$ itself).

Now let $F$ be the limit function of such a sequence. Show that $F$ is also holomorphic, injective and that $F(D)$ is also bounded by $|z| = 1$ and some continuum $C_\infty$ in $|z|<1$ such that $0 \not \in F(D)$.

I have some hints how to do that. Obviously $F$ is also holomorphic in $D$ and I already showed using Hurwitz's theorem that $F$ is non-zero and injective. What I need to show now is that $|F(z)| = 1$ for $|z|=1$. The hint for that goes like this:

> Show that the convergence of $(f_n)$ on some loop $\gamma \subset D$ around the origin implies the convergence of the analytic continuations of $(f_n)$ on the curve $\gamma^*$ which is the reflection of $\gamma$ on $|z|=1$. Then follow $|f_n(z)-f_m(z)| \rightarrow 0$ for $n,m \rightarrow \infty$ and $|z|=1$ using the Maximum principle.

I already showed that the continuations converge on $\gamma^*$ when $(f_n)$ converges on $\gamma$ using the reflection principle. But how do I show $|f_n(z)-f_m(z)| \rightarrow 0$ for $n,m \rightarrow \infty$ and $|z|=1$ using the Maximum principle? And how does this imply $|F(z)|=1$ for $|z|=1$?

Answer (score 1):

$f_n$ converges uniformly on $\gamma*$ means that $f_n-f_m$ converges uniformly to zero there by the Cauchy convergence criterion, but now applying the Cauchy integral theorem to express $(f_n-f_m)(z)$ on the unit circle in terms of $(f_n-f_m)(\zeta)$ on $\gamma*$ we have uniform integral convergence as the denominator is bounded away so we get $f_n-f_m$ converges uniformly on $|z|=1$

for the second point, this means that $f_n \to F$ hence $|f_n| \to |F|$ on the unit circle too, but $|f_n(w)|=1$ for all $|w|=1$ and all $n$ since by hypothesis $|f_n(w)| \le 1$ and if for some $n,|w|=1$ we have $|f_n(w)| <1$ we can pick a $|y|<1$, $f(y)=f(w)$ and get a contradiction to injectivity near $w$ inside the unit circle and $y$ since $B_{\delta}(f(y)) \subset f_n(B_{\epsilon}(y))$ for small enough $\epsilon, \delta(\epsilon)$, while $f(B_{\alpha}(w)) \cap D$ is open and nonempty)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain a little bit more how you "express $(f_n-f_m)(z)$ on the unit circle in terms of $(f_n-f_m)(\zeta)$ on $\gamma*$" using the Cauchy integral theorem and how this implies the uniform convergence of $f_n-f_m$ on $|z|=1$? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Cauchy theorem on the domain bounded by $\gamma, \gamma^*$ which contains the unit circle, (uniform convergence on $\gamma$ too - given in the OP) and distance from the unit circle to $\gamma, \gamma^*$ bounded away by compacity of $C$

Comment: Sorry but I dont get how you apply the Cauchy integral theorem in this scenario. Could you please explain that a little bit more in depth? Thank you!

Comment: The Cauchy formula $2\pi if(z)=\int_{\partial A}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}dz$ is still valid for a domain $A$ bounded by two simple curves and $z$ inside where the boundary curves are taken appropriately oriented - apply this for the domain bunded by $\gamma^*, \gamma$ which contains the unit circle inside (so the formula is valid at any point there), use the fact the denominator is bounded away (for both circles) and use uniform convergence on the two boundary curves to conclude same on the unit circle